# Angular Web API $http post exclude list

Tags: angularjs, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API (2) project which has departments and employees. An employee has a department, and a department has a list of employees.

Now in the frontend, when creating or editing an employee, the user must select a department. When posting this to the API, the department contains the list of employees (which causes an invalid modelstate), how can I prevent this?

This is my relevant setup:

Models:

```
public class Employee : IEntity, ICreatedOn, IModifiedOn, IMappable
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    // .. other properties
}

public class Department : IEntity, IMappable
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    // .. other properties
}
```

Web API controller:

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeesController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        this._employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    // .. GET, POST, DELETE etc.

    // PUT: api/Employees/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutEmployee(int id, EmployeeVM employee)
    {
        // This is always invalid, because the employee has a department, which in turn has a list of employees which can be invalid
        // What to do to exclude the list of employees from validation, or even better prevent from being sent to the API
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Update etc..

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Angular (DataService.js):

```
app.factory('DataService',
    ["$http",
    function ($http) {

        return {
            // other functions
            updateEmployee: _updateEmployee
        }

        function _updateEmployee(employee) {

            // Maybe exclude the list of employees in employee.department in here??
            return $http.put(employeesUrl + "/" + employee.id, employee);
        }

        // .. other functions
    }]);
```

Notes:

- It happens in both the Put and the Post (updating and creating)
- I'm using AutoMapper for mapping to the ViewModels, which look the same as the entities
- I'm using Entity Framework for the ORM

What I've tried:

- [JsonIgnore] attribute on the Employees collection; this causes the Employees also not being loaded when loading the Department
- [Bind(Exclude = "Employees")] attribute in the controller action parameters, this did not have any effect
- [Bind(Exclude = "Department.Employees")] same

What works, but I'm sure there must be a better solution:

```
function _updateEmployee(employee) {

    var newEmp = angular.copy(employee);
    delete newEmp.department.employees;
    return $http.put(employeesUrl, newEmp);
}
```

Comment: show your EmployeeVM please

Answer (score 1):

Create a new request for updating your `employee`. Like:

```
public class UpdateEmployeeRequest{
     public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
     public int DepartmentId {get;set;}
     //and so on
}
```

For this request you can specify concrete validation.

And declare Entities with explicit ID.:

```
public class Employee : IEntity, ICreatedOn, IModifiedOn, IMappable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "Department" )]
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    // .. other properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the Employee entity like this

```
    public class Employee : IEntity, ICreatedOn, IModifiedOn, IMappable
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        //Add DepartmentId
        public Guid? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

        // .. other properties
    }
```

Then you can only set DepartmentId and that's it. EF will take care of the rest